# anguar passing value from input to model

Tags: angular

I am making a put request. How can i pass  value from input  form  to my model to pass value that i am filling up - before send form. everything what i have tried it had been thrown errors.

my model .ts file

```
 export class Uniticket {
          pk?: string;
          sk?: string;
          PK?: string;
          SK?: string;
          ticketid?: number;
          createdate?: Date;
          status?: string;
          interactionid?: string;
          subject?: string;
          body?: string;
          user?: string;
          entitytype?: string;
          lastupdate?: Date;
          lastupdateuser?: string;
        }
```

my html :

```
 <form #userPost="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <mat-form-field appearance="legacy">
        <input
          matInput
          type="text"
          name="ticketid"
          id="ticketid"
          [(ngModel)]="ticketid"
        />
        <mat-icon *matSuffix>how_to_reg</mat-icon>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field appearance="legacy">
        <input
          matInput
          type="text"
          name="createdate"
          id="createdate"
          [(ngModel)]="createdate"
        />
<mat-icon matSuffix>calendar_today</mat-icon>
      </mat-form-field>
```

my type script component :

```
   export class TicketsFormComponent implements OnInit {
  ticketid: number = 0;
  createdate: string = '';
  interactionid: string = '';
  subject: string = '';
  body: string = '';
  user: string = '';

  constructor(private service: TicketsService) {}
  ngOnInit() {}
  public addTicket() {
    let resp = this.service.addTicket();
    resp.subscribe((report) => {
      console.log('report', report);
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this);
    this.addTicket();
  }
}
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You just need a button with `type='submit'` within your form

```html
<form #userPost="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  ...
  <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

That will trigger the function you've specified with `(ngSubmit)`

The data within the form is always synchronized with the data in your component as you've used the `[(ngModel)]` two-way binding. So to get the `ticketid` for example you can just use `this.ticketid`.

```js
  onSubmit() {
    //Log the ticket id from the form
    console.log(this.ticketid);
  }
```

Comment: and could you show me how it pass to request ? I will be greatfull

Comment: Use the `HttpClient` service to make http requests. https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient

Comment: You need to import `HttpClientModule` into your app.module.ts or any other module which you are using and the make a service to call your API(and probably pass the variable in it). For more information please refer to this [article](https://www.djamware.com/post/5b87894280aca74669894414/angular-httpclient-678910-consume-rest-api-example)

Answer (score 0):

The ng-submit directive specifies a function to run when the form is submitted. If the form does not have an action ng-submit will prevent the form from being submitted.

Comment: or you can use the form builder it s simple just flow the documentation
https://angular.io/start/start-forms